Practical Implementation of Slope Compensation
I am trying to understand and practically apply slope compensation. The IC I intend to use is the LM25037. The datasheet explains slope compensation in detail, which I have understood, and I know why slope compensation is necessary, etc. I was able to derive equation (5) from the datasheet as well.
However, I don't fully understand the practical implementation, specifically the determination of Rslope. While the datasheet provides a formula for this, I am confused because I don't fully grasp it.

How could I derive this formula? Also, why isn't Cfilter included in the formula? It is obviously possible to solve this with Laplace, but I don't exactly understand for what I need to determine the voltage as a function of time.

If I understand correctly, the time dependency of the RAMP voltage needs to be determined. I have done this, but the result is a transcendental equation, making it impossible to express Rslope (R1). In my calculations, I neglected Cfilter. According to TI, the impedance of Cfilter and Rfilter should be kept low to ensure proper slope compensation. Naturally, Cfilter also has some influence.
Even Mathcad struggles with the equation: (R1 = Rslope, R2 = Rfilter, C=Cslope, I neglected Rcs as it is too small compared to Rfilter.):

Any ideas?

C filter is irrelevant to the discussion of slope compensation, so you can ignore it when trying to understand the formula. An ideal converter doesn't need Cfilter at all. One does need it in practice tho, to prevent the turn-on current spike from triggering the current limit immediately (see bottom two traces in your graphic)
